# Variables cambian de valor en php

Tags: php, laravel

Amigos, estoy un poco confundido con variables que utilizo en una funcion de php, estoy trabajado un backend con laravel 8 y estoy usando el carbon para trbajar con fechas, y tengo algo como esto

```
public function generaFechasSemana(Request $request)
{
    $finicio=Carbon::parse($request->finicio);
    $ffin=Carbon::parse($request['ffin'].' 23:59:00');

    $num = 1;
    $fechas=[];
    $ano =$finicio->year;
    $mes =$finicio->month;
    echo $mes;
    //obtengo el primer lunes del mes
    $primerLunes =$this->PrimerLunesDelMes($ano, $mes);
    //obtengo el numero de dias del mes
    $number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);
    //seteo el ultimo dia del mes
    $ultimoDiaMes = new DateTime();
    $ultimoDiaMes->setDate($ano, $mes, $number);
    /creo la fecha con el primer dia del mes 
    $primerDia = Carbon::create($ano,$mes, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    $primerDia1=$primerDia;
    //creo una fecha del primer lunes del mes
    $primerDiaDate = Carbon::create($ano,$mes, $primerLunes, 0, 0, 0);

    if ($primerDiaDate > $primerDia){

        $ffinal=$primerDia1->addDays($primerLunes-2);

        $fecha=new FechaSemana();
        $fecha->numero=$num;
        $fecha->finicio=$primerDia;
        $fecha->ffinal=$ffinal;
        $fechas[$num]=$fecha;
        $num++;
    }
```

En esta parte cuando se ejecuta esta linea

```
$ffinal=$primerDia1->addDays($primerLunes-2);
```

Veo que la variable ahora $primerDia y $primerDia1 y el $ffinal tienen el mismo valor, no se si las variables usan la misma referencia en memoria pero cuando cambio a una variable el valor cambia en todas
Al retonar el vector de fechas me retorna lo siguiente:

```
{
    "err": false,
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Cargado correctamente",
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "numero": 1,
            "finicio": "2022-07-03T05:00:00.000000Z",
            "ffinal": "2022-07-03T05:00:00.000000Z"
        }
    }
}
```

En la primera posicion del vectos tenfo el finicio y ffinal el mismo valor, Porque sucede esto?

Comment: Buen día, cuando utilizas `$primerDia1->addDays()` estás sumando días a la variable `$primerDia1` y luego asignas la nueva fecha a `$ffinal`, si deseas conservar la fecha original en `$primerDia1` y una fecha diferente en `$ffinal` puedes hacer algo así `$ffinal = $primerDia1` y en una segunda línea `$ffinal->addDays($primerLunes-2);`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero  me funciono hice este cambio $ffinal=$primerDia; y en otra linea  $ffinal->addDays($primerLunes-2); y aun se cambia el valor en la variable $primerDia;

Comment: Amigos lo resolvi con el metodo copy, de carbon, de esta forma $ffinal = $primerDia1->copy();